# how do you make rocket jumping in godot

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have been having some problems in making rocket jumping in Godot using GDscript I cannot add any code here as everything i try to do always fails

Comment: You can provide the code you tried and failed. This would serve as a starting point to help you.

Comment: Nobody is expecting you to post code that works correctly on the question. Au contraire, we expect the code that is not working. Or at least an explanation of what you tried, what are you trying to do and how it went wrong. This site is for programming problems, after all. On that note, you may also be interested in https://gamedev.stackexchange.com which will accept other question related to game development that don't fit well on this site. *I don't mean they will take all the questions, they have their rules too. Sometimes Godot's own q&a is better: https://godotengine.org/qa/*.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking about rocket jumping, I'll assume you already have a projectile weapon working, and you already have a character controller working.

The next step is to make an explosion. Go ahead and make an explosion scene. When the projectile collides with the scenario or another character, you will spawn the explosion scene, and `queue_free` the projectile.

For the explosion scene, you probably want to set up a particle system, let it play for a predetermined time, and then `queue_free` the explosion scene too. But that is not the part that is relevant for rocket jumping.

What you need is an `Area` in the explosion scene, that represent the blast radius. The idea is that everything inside the `Area` (everything that triggers `"body_entered"` on the `Area`) can take damage and can be pushed away. *You can further refine using a `RayCast` if you want allow characters to take cover. But again, that is not relevant for rocket jumping, so I suggest get it working without the `RayCast` and you can add it later if you want.*

---

Alright, so you got a `body` in the `"body_entered"` signal of the `Area` that represents the blast radius of the explosion spawned by the projectile when it collided. Then what?

You want a vector that goes from the explosion to that body. That would be like this:

```
var vector := body.global_transform.origin - global_transform.origin
```

*I remind you, this goes in the function for the `"body_entered"` signal.*

In fact, we want the unit vector:

```
var vector := body.global_transform.origin - global_transform.origin
var direction := vector.normalized()
```

And the distance:

```
var vector := body.global_transform.origin - global_transform.origin
var direction := vector.normalized()
var distance := vector.length()
```

Squared:

```
var vector := body.global_transform.origin - global_transform.origin
var direction := vector.normalized()
var distance_squared := vector.length_squared()
```

Now, the idea is that you will apply to the body a velocity proportional to the inverse of the distance squared. You want the velocity to be configurable, and tweak it for the needs of your game, so add a export variable on the top of the script:

```
var export speed := 10.0
```

And we compute the velocity:

```
var vector := body.global_transform.origin - global_transform.origin
var direction := vector.normalized()
var distance_squared := vector.length_squared()
var velocity := direction * speed/distance_squared
```

*I'm trying to mimic the inverse square law. But, it is your game, if you find that using the `distance` instead of `distance_squared` works better, or you want to make the velocity decay differently, or not at all, go ahead and change it.*

---

If the body is a `RigidBody` we can apply an impulse or set the linear velocity. *And you probably should do that anyway, so the explosion can knock down other objects.* But your player character probably is a `KinematicBody`, right?

Now, I don't know how the code for your player character looks like (*you haven't added your code to the question*), so I don't know you would apply a velocity to it.

However, most tutorials for player character will have you set a velocity vector, and the idea is that we will add the velocity we computed to it. Assuming yours is similar, that should be something like this:

```
body.velocity += velocity
```

But, of course, that should only be for your characters. So you should filter for that. If they have a `class_name` you probably can do this (assuming here that they are `class_name Character`):

```
if body is Character:
    body.velocity += velocity
```

---

By the way, this will push everything with the same velocity. It probably should push lighter object more and heavier objects less. *For the RigidBody, you would apply a force instead of an impulse.* So you could declare a mass in your characters and take into account for computing the velocity. *But, again, get the simple version working first.*